# Crystal Report - How to deal with empty data?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have sub report linked with EmployeeID. But for some employees I don't have data so report get suppressed. And I get record at wrong place. I want to avoid this so what can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

> I get record at wrong place

What do you mean the wrong place? Don't you mean the sub-report is taking up space when there are no records for an employee?

It depends on the sub-report layout, but I usually make the sub-report very thin in the main report and then I'll set suppress formulas in the visible sub-report sections. That can be done with an isnull() check on some key. I think there is also a special keyword you can use to check if there are records, I forget the name though.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the section suppress option on all the sections of the sub-report. I believe you can tie the section suppression to a formula. In that formula you need to check against the record count variable(I forget the exact name) and return a boolean in that formula to show/hide the given section.