# If my SQL query in Crystal Report is not returning any data then how can I stop it from displaying

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I want to stop printing of reports if no data is returned in Crystal Report. How can that be achieved?

Comment: Is this question related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/17538863/1467396 ? (Note: that one doesn't have an answer, either. Just curious if they are different)  What about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1069435/1467396 ?

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this is to put the logic from the main report into a subreport.  Then on the main report, right click on your newly created subreport and choose Format Subreport, select the Subreport Tabe then check the box that says "Suppress Blank Subreport".

That is one way to do it...